# Confusion about matrix derivative/chain rule

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, chain-rule

I have a vector Z of which depends on time. I am looking to find $\ddot\sigma(Z)$, the second time derivative of $\sigma$.

$$Z = \begin{bmatrix} z_1\\ z_2\\ z_3\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

And $\sigma$ is defined as follows:

$$ \sigma(z_k) =  \frac{\mathrm{1} }{\mathrm{1} + e^{-z_k} }  $$

$$\sigma(Z) = \begin{bmatrix} \sigma(z_1)\\ \sigma(z_2)\\ \sigma(z_3)\\ \end{bmatrix} $$

It is my understanding that $\dot\sigma(Z)$ should be equal to $\frac{\partial{\sigma}}{\partial{Z}}\cdot\frac{\partial{Z}}{\partial{t}}$ Which in our case evaluates to the Jacobian of $\sigma(Z)$ times the time derivative of Z:

$$\dot\sigma(Z) = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial\sigma(z_1)}{\partial{z_1}}& 0& 0\\ 0& \frac{\partial\sigma(z_2)}{\partial{z_2}}& 0 \\ 0&0&\frac{\partial\sigma(z_3)}{\partial{z_3}}\\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \dot z_1\\ \dot z_2\\ \dot z_3\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

If the above is right, my question is then what would $\ddot\sigma(Z)$ be? I attempt to use the product rule, but the dimensions don't work out properly (and I'm not really sure if I'm using the "chain rule" properly here)

$$\ddot\sigma(Z) = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial\sigma(z_1)}{\partial{z_1}}& 0& 0\\ 0& \frac{\partial\sigma(z_2)}{\partial{z_2}}& 0 \\ 0&0&\frac{\partial\sigma(z_3)}{\partial{z_3}}\\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \ddot z_1\\ \ddot z_2\\ \ddot z_3\\ \end{bmatrix} +\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial^2\sigma(z_1)}{\partial{z_1}^2}& 0& 0\\ 0& \frac{\partial^2\sigma(z_2)}{\partial{z_2}^2}& 0 \\ 0&0&\frac{\partial^2\sigma(z_3)}{\partial{z_3}^2}\\ \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \dot z_1\\ \dot z_2\\ \dot z_3\\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \dot z_1\\ \dot z_2\\ \dot z_3\\ \end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: Why do you want to write this in matrix form? The coordinates are independent so you can find the second derivative and just stack the result. In the last term in your second derivative the dimensions dont match up, youre missing a transpose. Check The Matrix Cookbook for help with derivatives involving matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a scalar argument, the derivatives/differentials of the function are
$$\eqalign{
\sigma'(z_k) &= \frac{d\sigma}{dz_k}\quad\implies\quad d\sigma = \sigma'dz_k \\
\sigma''(z_k) &= \frac{d\sigma'}{dz_k}\quad\implies\quad d\sigma' = \sigma''dz_k \\
}$$
When applied *element-wise* to vectors, these evaluate to vectors
$$s = \sigma(z),\quad s'=\sigma'(z),\quad s''=\sigma''(z)$$
and the differentials must be written using the *element-wise* (aka Hadamard) product
$$ds = s'\odot dz,\qquad ds' = s''\odot dz$$
Since the time derivatives/differentials of $z$ are related by
$$dz = \dot z dt,\qquad d\dot z = \ddot z dt$$
the time derivatives of $s$ can be calculated as
$$\eqalign{
ds &= s'\odot\dot z \, dt \\
\dot s &= s'\odot\dot z \\\\
d\dot s
 &= ds'\odot\dot z + s'\odot d\dot z \\
 &= (s''\odot dz)\odot\dot z + s'\odot(\ddot z dt) \\
 &= (s''\odot\dot z\odot\dot z + s'\odot\ddot z)\,dt \\
\ddot s &= s''\odot\dot z\odot\dot z + s'\odot\ddot z \\
}$$
One final trick, is that Hadamard multiplication by a vector can be replaced by first converting the vector into a diagonal matrix and then performing normal matrix multiplication, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
a\odot b &= {\rm Diag}(a)\,b \;=\; Ab \\
{\rm Diag}(a\odot b) &= AB = BA \quad 
\big({\rm diagonal\,matrices\,commute}\big) \\
}$$
So these results can be written using diagonal matrices as
$$\eqalign{
\dot S &= S'\dot Z \\
\ddot S &= S''\dot Z^2 + S'\ddot Z \\
}$$
or as a mixture of matrices and vectors
$$\eqalign{
\dot s &= \dot Zs' \\
\ddot s &= \dot Z^2s'' + \ddot Zs' \\
}$$
NB: In the case of the [Logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function#Derivative) the derivatives are given by simple formulas
$$\eqalign{
\sigma' &= (\sigma-\sigma^2)
&\implies S'=(S-S^2) &\implies s'=(I-S)s \\
\sigma'' &= (\sigma-3\sigma^2+2\sigma^3)\;
&\implies S''=(S-3S^2+2S^3)\;
&\implies s''=(I-3S+2S^2)s \\
}$$